# Android TurnBasedMultiplayer auto matching with exclusiveBitMask

Tags: java, android, multiplayer, bitmask, google-play-games

Can someone explain how this bitmask parameter might be used to auto-match exclusive roles in a game? Does it seem possible to auto-match multiple players of unique roles?

It is mentioned here [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#selecting_players_with_the_default_user_interface)

> Your game can also use the exclusiveBitMask parameter in
>   createAutoMatchCriteria() to pair auto-matched players who are
>   interested in playing specific exclusive roles in a game.

and also the [api docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchConfig.html)

```
public static Bundle createAutoMatchCriteria (int minAutoMatchPlayers,
                             int maxAutoMatchPlayers, long exclusiveBitMask)
```

> Creates an auto-match criteria Bundle. Can be passed to
>      createMatch(GoogleApiClient, TurnBasedMatchConfig) to create a match
>   for a turn-based game.
>
> Parameters minAutoMatchPlayers    min number of auto-matched players.
>   maxAutoMatchPlayers   max number of auto-matched players.
>   exclusiveBitMask  exclusive bitmask for exclusive roles for the player.
>   The exclusive bitmask of each pairing of players must equal zero for
>   auto-match.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> When auto-matching with this option, players will only be considered for a match when the logical AND of their exclusive bit masks is equal to 0.

So if you have a bit set in this mask, your opponents CANNOT have that bit set as well, if they want to be paired to you.

E.g. in chess, if A wants to play white, and B wants to play black, they can specify this in this mask (0x1 for white, 0x2 for black), and can be paired.
Two players wanting to play white will not be matched.

A player with mask 0x0 can be paired with any player, either as white or as black.

Answer (score 0):

"The exclusive bitmask of each pairing of players must equal zero for auto-match" essentially means that the exclusiveBitMask must be the exact same between players. The usefulness would be limited. That doesn't mean you couldn't create a bit mask that represents role A and role B if the relationships were that simple. But it would mean it would match players with either role A or B and it would need to be filtered. If role A could also match with role C then the user would have to select a filter that matches A+B or A+C but not both.

Comment: Mask must be *different* in all bits, not 'exact same' as you write.